# Lumia 520 app crashing

Tags: lumia-520, lumia

Iam using Lumia 520 from 2014 ...it's work like a charm  one fine day early morning I noticed that WhatsApp is not working even the application itself is not opening at all.. Few days Later all the apps and even in-built apps are also not working..i thought that its some error or something like that wen I thought after reset every thing will be fine but no use after couple of resets I faced same problem.... I have done hard reset soft reset...and from today evening calendar music player also not working...its like a useless trash mobile .. iam using Windows 8.1 update ..Help me out guys

Comment: Lumia 520 is a low memory device. This problem may arise due to low memory. How much free space do you have in the internal memory.

Comment: 2.5GB  memory is there bro.

Comment: I am using 520, i dont find any difficulty in using it, try doing a sot reset

Comment: Do you use a SD card? Does this apps are installed in this SD card?

Answer (score -1):

I Have the same issue.

I think this is a trick used by Microsoft just like apple's does "Apple: Yes, we're slowing down older iPhones" - CNN, 2017.

What worked for me (at least for a few months) was restoring the initial OS using "Windows Device Recovery Tool Installer", you will need to connect your phone to PC via USB and the rest the app will do - Might take a while tho. **DON'T FORGET TO BACKUP!**